# How to get waitpid on Ubuntu 13.04

Tags: ubuntu

To my knowledge, waitpid should be working out of the box in Terminal. But it didn't.

It gives me `waitpid: command not found` when running in Terminal, and `Unknown syscall 'waitpid'` when trying to use an tool that uses waitpid.

What should I do to get it? Is that included on some other package?

Answer (score 1):

Try `wait`. This is a `bash` builtin command, and it accepts a PID as argument.